# Buscar una propiedad de un objeto por su valor, y a su vez recoger otros delmismo. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una consulta. Partiendo de la función y el objeto que veis, tengo una aplicación que lanzará un estado (una cadena de caracteres) que está en una variable. Necesito buscar el valor de una propiedad dentro de un objeto y si existe, éste recoja otros dos valores más del mismo nivel.

Por tanto si el estado que le envío es "estado2", pueda enviar a otra función guardado en una variable el texto de su nivel ("Prueba texto2") y en otra el tipo ("negativo"). La función para encontrar una propiedad para el estado la tengo, pero lo que necesito es esto, que si me encuentra el "estado2", me capture SOLO los de ese nivel, y eso es lo que no consigo... cómo tengo que enfocar el desarrollo?.

```
var matrizObjeto = {
        0: {
            "Texto": "Prueba texto1",
            "Estado": "estado1",
            "Tipo": "positivo"
        },
        1: {
            "Texto": "Prueba texto2",
            "Estado": "estado2",
            "Tipo": "negativo"
        },
        2: {
            "Texto": "Prueba texto3",
            "Estado": "estado3",
            "Tipo": "negativo"
        }
    };

    var estado = "estado2";
    var parcialEstado;
    var parcialTexto;
    var parcialTipo


    function searchObj(obj, query) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            var value = obj[key];
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                searchObj(value, query);
            }
            if (value === query) {
                (estado === value) ? parcialClave = value : alert("no");
            }
        }
    }

    searchObj(matrizObjeto, estado);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun lo que entiendo quieres hacer esto:

```
function searchObj(obj, query) {
    for (k in obj) {
        if (obj[k]['Estado'] === query){
            return [ obj[k]['Texto'], obj[k]['Tipo']];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a ver, partiendo que quieres encontrar y capturar la información que hay en dicho objeto por el estado de cada "sub-objeto" (o nivel como lo llamos tu) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    text: "Some dummy text in obj[0]",
    status: "status_0",
    type: "negative"
  },
  1: {
    text: "Some dummy text in obj[1]",
    status: "status_1",
    type: "negative"
  },
  2: {
    text: "Some dummy text in obj[2]",
    status: "status_2",
    type: "negative"
  },
};

function findInObj(obj, status) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var val = obj[key].status;
    if (status == val) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(obj[key], null, 4)); // Aquí obtienes todo el objeto de tu nivel
      alert(obj[key].text);                     // <- Aquí obtienes el text de tu nivel
      alert(obj[key].status);                   // <- Aquí obtienes el status de tu nivel
      alert(obj[key].type);                     // <- Aquí obtienes el type de tu nivel
    }
  }
}

findInObj(obj, "status_0");
```

Comment: Por qué se pone el número 4 como parámetro después del null?, gracias!.

Comment: @djohny Es solo para darle un poco de formato a la salida y que se vea de una manera organizada

Comment: Entendido! gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, en tu funcion haces un `each` de tu arreglo

```
var matrizObjeto = {
    0: {
        "Texto": "Prueba texto1",
        "Estado": "estado1",
        "Tipo": "positivo"
    },
    1: {
        "Texto": "Prueba texto2",
        "Estado": "estado2",
        "Tipo": "negativo"
    },
    2: {
        "Texto": "Prueba texto3",
        "Estado": "estado3",
        "Tipo": "negativo"
    }
};
```

Jquery :

```
var parcialEstado = "";
var parcialTexto = "";
var parcialTipo = "";
function searchObj(estado) {
    $.each(matrizObjeto, function (index, value) {
      if(value.Estado == estado){
         parcialEstado = value.Estado;
         parcialTexto = value.Texto;
         parcialTipo = value.Tipo;
      }
    });
}
var estado = "estado2";
searchObj(estado);
console.log(parcialEstado);
console.log(parcialTexto);
console.log(parcialTipo);
```

Javascript

```js
var matrizObjeto = {
0: {
    "Texto": "Prueba texto1",
    "Estado": "estado1",
    "Tipo": "positivo"
},
1: {
    "Texto": "Prueba texto2",
    "Estado": "estado2",
    "Tipo": "negativo"
},
2: {
    "Texto": "Prueba texto3",
    "Estado": "estado3",
    "Tipo": "negativo"
}
};
var parcialEstado = "";
var parcialTexto = "";
var parcialTipo = "";

function searchObj(estado) {
for (var i in matrizObjeto) {
    if (matrizObjeto[i].Estado == estado) {
        parcialEstado = matrizObjeto[i].Estado;
        parcialTexto = matrizObjeto[i].Texto;
        parcialTipo = matrizObjeto[i].Tipo;
    }
}
}
var estado = "estado2";
searchObj(estado);
alert(parcialEstado);
alert(parcialTexto);
alert(parcialTipo);
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que habéis dado todos en la diana :) Ya que el programa que contiene el objeto / objetos a tratar es más fácil visualmente de reconocer la opción de Neyer, es la que usaré. Gracias a todos!!